# How to make the image inside an iframe fit to the size of the iframe? (angular)

Tags: css, angular, typescript, iframe

I'm wondering how to make the img content inside of my iframe fit to the size of my frame.  When i display a pdf inside of the iframe it scales perfectly but displaying a png looks bad because the image returned doesn't scale to its container.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)
[image: A picture of the images. I want to make them scale to the size of the container if possible. (and no I cant use an img tag to display because i have no way of telling whether it will be an image or a pdf doc.)]
[image: A picture of the pdf being rendered inside the frame (scaled to its size.)]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a simple webpage inside the iframe, so you can add a height and width to the image

Answer (score 0):

You can actually call object and load it inside it.

`<a :href="urlToImage" target="_blank">  <object :data="URLToImage" title="SamplePdf" width="200" height="150"> </object></a>`